# Google API (GoogleFit) : Auth Denied

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I use React native.

And I've followed all process to install Google Fit.
https://github.com/StasDoskalenko/react-native-google-fit/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md

Then, I check if this works.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      scopes: [Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ],
    };
    GoogleFit.authorize(options)
      .then((authResult) => {
        if (authResult.success) {
          console.log("AUTH SUCCESS");
        } else {
          console.log("AUTH DENIED");
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("AUTH_ERROR");
      });
  });
```

App asks me to choose account.

[image]

I write the account that I put user as test before.

[image]

But then, console says: `AUTH DENIED`

what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Double check your configuration, and verify if you have your SHA1, package name, etc., correctly declared in Google Cloud Console.

Uploading/attaching a screencap and logs of the error state/screen would be a plus as well.